# Microphone not working on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I would like to ask about the problem with a simple microphone volume level detection. My code works just fine with iOS 6 or lower but not iOS 7, my code looks like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{


NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                              nil];

    NSError *error;

    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

    if (recorder) {
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];


    } else{
        NSLog([error description]);
    }

}
// then call periodically with the following method, volumeLevelSampling
-(void)volumeLevelSampling{

    [recorder updateMeters];
    NSLog(@"Average input: %f Peak input: %f", [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0], [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]);


}
```

It works perfectly fine in iOS 6, however it's not sampling anything in iOS 7. The result is always -120.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue and when I check in Settings.app my app _is_ authorized to use the mic.

Comment: @EricPoon ... Could you fix this? Because i got an app that i can't record a sound from microphone, but only with iPad Air and iOS 7.

Answer (score 6):

Check in Settings if you have activated the permissions for your application. This works like the push notifications.

Once the alert is answered it wont pop up again. You have to go to:
`Settings -> Privacy -> Microphone` Then check the state of your app.

If you can't see your app there, it means that you are not correctly requesting access to the microphone. Try this.

```
if([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] respondsToSelector:@selector(requestRecordPermission:)]) {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (!granted) {
            NSLog(@"User will not be able to use the microphone!");
        }
    }];
}
```

Hope it helps as a clue.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 7 users must provide consent to apps that access the microphone.

Before you can use `AVAudioRecorder` you must first request this consent. This is done using the `requestAccessForMediaType:completionHandler:` method on `AVCaptureDevice`.

If you don't have consent - or you haven't requested it - you'll get silence when trying to record anything on iOS 7.

Comment: As a FYI for anyone reading this and Manuel's response, the docs also state "Invoking this method with `AVMediaTypeAudio` is equivalent to calling the `AVAudioSession` method `requestRecordPermission:`."

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and here is how I was able to make it work:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

if([audioSession respondsToSelector:@selector(requestRecordPermission:)]){
    //ios7
    [audioSession requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
        if(granted){
            [self recordNow];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"RECORD NOT AUTHORIZED");
        }
    }];
}else{
    //before ios7
    [self recordNow];
}
```

Comment: Do you have a problema with this routine in iPad Air? Because i got an app that i can't record a sound from microphone, but only with iPad Air.